# mdl-card expand to whole mdl-cell--x-col available

Tags: html, css, material-design, cells, material-design-lite

Whenever I create a mdl-card it is stuck at 330px wide, and even when I allocate classes `mdl-cell` `mdl-cell--12-col` or `mdl-cell--8-col` or anything, it just stays "mdl-cell--3-col" equivalent in width. How do I make the card use up the whole mdl-cell space I give it?

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code, are you using any of your own style sheets?

Speculating below:
One option is to set a class to the card div and then put the class in a style sheet as something like this

```
.card-full-width{width: 100%;}
```